# how Does /(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g work?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
function addTotal(checkValue, openAmount) {
        if(checkValue)
            totalOpenAmount += openAmount;
        else
            totalOpenAmount -= openAmount;

        if(blnUpdateCheckAll) updateAllChecked();

        document.getElementById('divTotalPayAmount').innerHTML = totalOpenAmount.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, '$1,');
    }
```

how does this **(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g)** work on this function ? it's telling that a number is at least 4 digits?

Comment: Most online regex testing websites offer a breakdown of what a regular expression does. Have you tried one? Set up an example for you here—https://regex101.com/r/WldKAq/1

Comment: Thanks it help me to understand those regular expression! @miqid

Answer (score 1):

`(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))`
Would translate to every third digit from the end of the last 3 digits in a numerical string and the last 3 digits of that numerical string. I'm not sure exactly how it is being used in the code but that is the regex.

Answer (score 1):

When it is used in code, the comma ","  will be connected after a three-digit of numerical string. Please check the code:

```js
var n = 1020304050;
document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = "This is a number: " +n;

var output = n.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "After using the regex the result is:  "+output;
console.log(output);

/* 
This is a number: 1020304050
After using the regex the result is:  1,020,304,050
*/
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <h3 id="number"></h3>
  <h3 id="result"></h3>

</body>

</html>
```